# Legend in barplot R

Tags: r, plot, graph, statistics, bar-chart

I am trying to make a bar graph in R, but I have a permanent recurring problem. The legend appears wrong and I can't fix it.

If anyone knows how to fix it, I will be very grateful. I attach a screenshot from R:

[image: Screenshot]

Thanks!

Comment: Please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve and edit your post

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what the exact issue is here since you posted a picture instead of a reproducible example, but the following code will give you the plot you want:

```r
dev.off()
par(mai = c(1, 1, 1, 2))

barplot(table(cuestionario$genero),
        main = "genero",
        col = c("blue", "pink"),
        ylab = "Cantidad",
        ylim = c(0, 400),
        beside = TRUE,
        legend.text = TRUE,
        args.legend = list(x = 3, y = 300))
```

[image]